# MySQL NOT LIKE '_%' not working on Wordpress woocommerce wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta large database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, meta-key, wordpress-database

I'm trying to search a Woocommerce mysql database for values that don't begin with `_` however when I use

```
WHERE meta_key LIKE '_%'
```

this works perfectly, however when using

```
WHERE meta_key NOT LIKE '_%'
```

this yields 0 results despite executing without any errors.

[image: Screenshot of Database Structure]

As you can see this is a typical wordpress database albeit with lots of rows. I also notice that meta_key has a default value of NULL, which makes me wonder if NULL values are causing the issue but surely mySQL would error if this was the case? If this is the case, is there a commonly accepted workaround for this whilst still allowing default of null values?

Answer (score 0):

Use Escape keyword

```
WHERE meta_key NOT LIKE '#_%' ESCAPE '#';
```

Please refer https://www.guru99.com/wildcards.html